# Prepopulated AWS Access Key ID when creating a new profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A new counter-party has provided me with an **AWS S3 Access Key ID** 
and a **Secret Key** so I can send files to them.

I was expecting to run

```
$ aws s3 configure
```

and enter those values when  prompted.

However, when I run `$aws s3 configure`
I get this

```
AWS Access Key ID [****************WXYZ]
```

when I was expecting this

expecting

```
AWS Access Key ID [None]:
```

[Amazon Read Me](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html)

**Questions**

When running `aws s3 configure` for a new instance should the `Key ID` value already contain something?

Am I taking the right approach to add a new profile to existing profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new profile, you need to use the `--profile` option.
To create a profile for your new foobar profile which you've named `aws_foobar`

`$ aws configure --profile aws_foobar`

By doing this the value for `Key ID` and `Secret Access Key` are blank

```
AWS Access Key ID [None]: FOOBAR_BLAH_KEY_ID...
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: blah...blah....AccessKeY
Default region name [None]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

[See Creating Multiple Profile Section Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration)